# cfmail group attribute throws error

Tags: coldfusion, cfquery, cfmail

I have a query which returns multiple results with just data in one column as different for a particular report number. I want to group the results for one report number and send an email to one person for all the action items. Below is my query

```
<cfquery name="qryCorrectiveDueDate" datasource="#application.config.DSN#">
    SELECT  FR.report_id,
            FR.report_number,
            IR.investigation_id,
            CA.action_who,
            CA.action_who_email,
            CA.action_what,
            CA.action_when,
            CA.action_type,
            CA.action_complete_date
    FROM    xyz_gir.dbo.xyz_flash_report AS FR,
            xyz_gir.dbo.xyz_investigation_report AS IR,
            xyz_gir.dbo.xyz_corrective_actions AS CA
    WHERE   FR.report_id = IR.report_id
    AND IR.investigation_id = CA.investigation_id
    AND DATEDIFF(day,CA.action_when,GETDATE()) > 1
    AND CA.action_complete_date IS NULL
    ORDER BY IR.investigation_id
</cfquery>
```

The Result Set looks something like this:

```
report_id   report_number   investigation_id    action_who  action_who_email     action_what    action_when action_type action_complete_date
2   13-0002 2   Hans-Joerg Wolf hans-joerg.wolf@xyz.com Action 1    00:00.0 Repair  NULL
4   13-0004 3   Robert Michael  robert.michael@xyz.com  fghfgh  00:00.0 Repair  NULL
5   13-0005 4   Masoud Aghel    Masoud.Aghel@xyz.com    sdfsdfsdf   00:00.0 Repair  NULL
5   13-0005 4   Masoud Aghel    Masoud.Aghel@xyz.com    hhjghj  00:00.0 Repair  NULL
```

What i want to do is send one email to the action_who_email value for multiple lines with the same investigation id. If i use cfoutput group attribute this is the output:

```
hans-joerg.wolf@xyz.com
Report ID: 2
Report Number:  13-0002
investigation id:   2
Action Who :Hans-Joerg Wolf
Action What: Action 1
Action When: 2013-04-26 00:00:00.0
Action type:Repair
Action Complete Date: 


robert.michael@xyz.com
Report ID: 4
Report Number:  13-0004
 investigation id:  3
Action Who :Robert Michael
Action What: fghfgh
Action When: 2013-05-05 00:00:00.0
Action type:Repair
Action Complete Date: 


Masoud.Aghel@xyz.com
Report ID: 5
Report Number:  13-0005
investigation id:   4
Action Who :Masoud Aghel
Action What: sdfsdfsdf
Action When: 2013-04-29 00:00:00.0
Action type:Repair
Action Complete Date: 

Report ID: 5
Report Number:  13-0005
investigation id:   4
Action Who :Masoud Aghel
Action What: hhjghj
Action When: 2013-04-29 00:00:00.0
Action type:Repair
Action Complete Date:
```

And This is my cfoutput:

```
<cfoutput query="qryCorrectiveDueDate" group="investigation_id">

<b>#action_who_email#</b><br>
    <cfoutput>
        Report ID: #report_id#</br>
        Report Number:  #report_number#</br>
        investigation id:   #investigation_id#</br>
            Action Who :#action_who#</br>
            Action What: #action_what#</br>
            Action When: #action_when#</br>
            Action type:#action_type#</br>
            Action Complete Date: #action_complete_date#</br></br>
    </cfoutput></br>

</cfoutput>
```

But if i do the same thing with cfmail on the query and group it, that throws a javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: 127.0.0.1, port: 25; error.

My CFMAIL code is as below

```
<cfmail query="qryCorrectiveDueDate" from="EHS@jdsu.com" to="#action_who_email#" group="#investigation_id#" subject="xyz">

<p>#action_who#,</p> 
<p>Due Dates for Corrective Actions for the Incident #report_number# have lapsed </p> 
<p>You are receiving this notification, as the Manager/Supervisor to implement the Corrective Actions </p> 
<p>Incident No: #report_number# </p> 
<p>Corrective Action: #action_what#</p> 
<p>Due Date: #action_when#</p> 

</cfmail>
```

Please note that i am running Coldfusion locally with xampp, and although the mails dont get delivered, i can see them in the undelivered folder in coldfusion. The same file has other cfmail tags which do not throw the connection exception if this cfmail tag is commented out. 
 I apologize if my question is very generic, but i either have to do this with coldfusion or i might have to write a function to treat my result set as a temp table. Its easier with coldfusion i believe, if i know how to make this work.

Comment: Can you please update your question and quantify what you mean by "does not work"?

Comment: This error would indicate that there isn't a mail server running on that host or port?

Comment: yes there is no mail server but i have other cfmail tags with similar to and from addresses and they simply go to the undelivered forlder in coldfusion. I dont get this particular error. Its just when i added this particular cfmail on the query i am encountering this error.

Comment: Is there any difference between this `cfmail` and your other `cfmail` tags?

Comment: The other cfmail tags are inside cfloop . This one is as below:                                                                <cfmail query="qryCorrectiveDueDate" from="EHS@jdsu.com" to="#action_who_email#" group="#investigation_id#" subject="xyz">
<p>#action_who#,</p> 
<p>Due Dates for Corrective Actions for the Incident #report_number# have lapsed  </p>
<p>You are receiving this notification, as the Manager/Supervisor to implement the Corrective Actions  </p>
<p>Incident No: #report_number# </p>
<p>Corrective Action: #action_what#</p>
<p>Due Date: #action_when#</p>
</cfmail>

Comment: The group attribute shouldn't have the # signs.  `group = "investigation_id"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that you've removed the hash tags, your issue is likely a missing `cfoutput` tag in the email. Similar to the group attribute of the `cfoutput` tag, you need another `cfoutput` tag to loop through the grouped records.

Tested on CF8 locally.

```
<cfmail query="q" group="field">
    <cfoutput>
        #field# - #field2#
    </cfoutput>
</cfmail>
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe your actual problem is that you're using pound signs in the group attribute.

`group="#investigation_id#"` should be `group="investigation_id"`

**--Edit--**

This below answer is moot as the OP was misleading.

I think this is because you do not need `cfoutput` tags inside the `cfmail` tag.  It's odd that it causes a mail error, though.

anyway...

I would try using `cfsavecontent` then output the variable in the `cfmail`.

```
<cfsavecontent variable = "mailBody">
    <cfoutput query="qryCorrectiveDueDate" group="investigation_id">
        <b>#action_who_email#</b><br>
        <cfoutput>
            Report ID: #report_id#</br>
            Report Number:  #report_number#</br>
            investigation id:   #investigation_id#</br>
            Action Who :#action_who#</br>
            Action What: #action_what#</br>
            Action When: #action_when#</br>
            Action type:#action_type#</br>
            Action Complete Date: #action_complete_date#</br></br>
        </cfoutput>
        </br> 
    </cfoutput>
</cfsavecontent>

<cfmail ...>
    #mailBody#
</cfmail>
```

Comment: Well i dont have cfoutput tags inside my cfmail. Also if i use savecontent that just sends one email to everyone with all the data. I want to send one separate email to (as per above mentioned result set) Masoud.Aghel@xyz.com with details of both the Action_what values of he same report ID and one separate email to robert and so on

Comment: @amsko *"this is my output... But if i do the same thing with cfmail ... "* led me to believe you did the same thing in your `cfmail` sorry for misunderstanding. You should show your `cfmail` code that's actually causing the error and not the superfluous stuff.

Comment: @MichaelGiovanniPumo that edit was not needed.  rolling back, it was copied from the OP and that <cfoutput> is needed to group the output. bad little man.

Comment: @Travis Apologies, it was a knee-jerk edit. I didn't notice the group clause. It's been a long morning! :)

Comment: I know those mornings well. :)

Comment: I removed the ##'s (That was basic.. i should have known that :( ) but now the issue is in the email to Masoud.Aghel@xyz.com  it has details of only one of the Action Whats not both (see result set or cfoutput data)

Comment: First thing I would check is, did you change the query or did the data change that would effect the query outuput? do a cfdump of the query and make sure you are getting the expected results.

Comment: Already checked that.. i get 4 rows of data, as i have posted in originally. But the email only has : `code` Report ID: 5
Report Number:  13-0005
investigation id:   4
Action Who :Masoud Aghel
Action What: sdfsdfsdf
Action When: 2013-04-29 00:00:00.0
Action type:Repair
Action Complete Date: 
`code` And Not: `code`
Report ID: 5
Report Number:  13-0005
investigation id:   4
Action Who :Masoud Aghel
Action What: hhjghj
Action When: 2013-04-29 00:00:00.0
Action type:Repair
Action Complete Date:

Comment: I hate that comments can't be formatted any better.   The docs say that the group attribute *"Eliminates adjacent duplicates when data is sorted by the specified field."* I don't think this makes much sense but try not sorting by this filed in the query.